# Best practices: What's the best way to treat byte protocol

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a serial communication with a device that has its own protocol, in other words, it has some byte arrays (frames) with some meaning. So, I have been treating it with a lot of default frames in a map to send data to the device and a kind of state machine, a big switch-case block to receive data from the device.

I know this question is subjective but I really would like to receive best practices to implement this relationship. Maybe there are design patterns to do the same.

Comment: state-machine is the preferred approach in M2M communication (IMHO) and the switch statement is a working approach if the machine won't grow too big. If it does or requires more flexibility, you may want to use a configurable automata framework or write one yourself. BUT your question is very broad and I think it should be rephrased and backed with some source or I suppose it will be closed as "too broad". It will attract opinion based answers.

Comment: Thanks @thst. Do you have some links, examples about automata frameworks? 
I know it's very broad but I really don't know how ask this in another way and it have already been worried me a lot for too much time. Also, there aren't much sources to search about it.

Comment: I have found the state pattern. It seems to be a good implementation to occasions when I have states with complex computations.

Comment: You can find some implementations here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875317/recommended-fsm-finite-state-machine-library-for-java

Comment: A good way to rephrase the question is to present a representative part of your implementation, for example the byte-reading-switch-loop. Then others may comment on your implementation and suggest different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how complex it is. If it's something as hairy as 3270 you certainly need a state machine. If it's a simple byte protocol you don't need anything more complex than a `DataInputStream.` There's not enough information here to say which.